# Excel sum rows on defined table and multiply by values in defined table header

Tags: excel

is there any way to sum rows and multiply by values from the headers of the defined table?

I tried something like:
`=SUMPRODUCT(Data[[#Headers],[£50]:[£100]],Data[[£50]:[£100]])`
obviously without any success...

table looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Just multiply the entire body of the table with the headers. If your data was to sit in `A1:C9` then `SUMPRODUCT(A2:C9*A1:C1)` should work

Comment: I am even embarrassed! :) 
Thanks a lot!!